# Making failed build unstable Jenkins

Tags: groovy, jenkins, continuous-integration, hudson

In Jenkins job, I occasionally get false failure over env issues. In those cases I rather get unstable build then "failed" (it has a lot of impact to the whole CI).

How can I mitigate build result post build? 
I've tried groovy postbuild :
`manager.buildUnstable()`
but it didn't work...

Answer (score 0):

Use **[Text Finder plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Text-finder+Plugin)**. Look for tell-tale signs for your condition (print a text message if you need to), and then configure the plugin to mark build as `UNSTABLE` when fond.